# Marklogic REST API - Retrieve File Content

Tags: rest, xslt, web-applications, marklogic

I'm currently working to build an app on top of a MarkLogic database of XML documents. These are news articles in NEWSML-G2 format. I'm using a REST API that I created in the Information Studio to access the database. Using the /search API call, I can retrieve a set of documents matching with the keyword. I would like to apply an XSLT and display these as a list, with the title of each article being shown. I've looked through the MarkLogic documentation and elsewhere, but could not find relevant material. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krishna:

If you're using MarkLogic 7, you can do the following:

First, Create query options that extract the title of each document:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_94425

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/config/query/%5B%27default%27-or-name%5D

Then, install your XSLT transform on the REST server:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/config/transforms/%5Bname%5D

Finally, specify your query options and your XSLT transform to modify the search response:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum